# Spring RestTemplate get raw json

Tags: java, character-encoding, resttemplate, spring-rest

I am using spring restTemplate to consume some rest service which gives me json response. My problem is that when I get the response, it consists of all weird characters instead of simple json response which server is providing. Initially I thought its simple charcter encoding problem but even after setting correct converters I am getting problem. My code -

```
RestTemplate restTemplate1 = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate1.getMessageConverters().add(0, new StringHttpMessageConverter(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
responseEntity = restTemplate1.exchange(uri, request.getMethod(),
            new HttpEntity<String>(body, requestHeaders), String.class);
```

Request headers are created as follows -

```
private MultiValueMap<String, String> getHeadersInfo(HttpServletRequest request) {

        MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();

        map.put("Accept", Arrays.asList("text/plain, text/plain, application/json, application/*+json, */*, */*"));
        map.put("Content-Type", Arrays.asList("application/json; charset=UTF-8"));

        return map;
    }
```

Also, if I use getForObject instead of exchange method (as following), then I get the correct result but I can't use this as I need to add some headers.

```
String a = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class);
```

I have checked many blogs and stackoverflow questions but they all have suggested the techniques which I have already tried here.

Any suggestions?

Type of response I am getting -

```
???Oo7???x???4?K\???[?Ð??H??v? ??K?????^\?y???/M???vw???Y?0?6???U???Q????????K?=N{?rZ??n-??8????-?l????????7C?l?????~"???a???Z????U3???3?9???)?J?+???n???d?????? ???\??\o?????? ?????????n????t??2`   ???8KLK?R?IJ1????t?\k?û?????j??^#???n??????{??aUV?g\?Q???p? ?V?z???w?R??????   >(IsL,?)?&?TH??.+/LU?Eq??????)??m????n??,4?9hn?{?f18??Z?jW ??5x?JOH%@0$?"?-Ra/??QA;.??*fN@?U?(?????~????s???#??X=W?l?????????Y?T??AR?R???WC=?L^A"t$?R4]J?m]M]???J??my ??ic?,;7OH??}?????'^J????????"'?R????X?X???&???"?`?2^y?-?? i???M??A??ljWu?/|!?qs?v{i?N?'?r?L??3???e??PNV'-.? SN?Y?????:d[#?]?????Wg?,???????????vdq6e?????#Yb??=pM??@<)$ ?8W\???ItQ?P/?R??P?7????:???
```

Comment: did you try to test the resource by another client (like browser or postman)?

Comment: Yes.. Also, I inspected in debug mode and it shows same weird response

Comment: So, it's a problem of the exposed resource and not your client

Comment: But if I use String a = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class); then it works fine... Also, I can hit the exposed resource directly in a browser too and there also it works fine

Comment: I found the issue.. unknowingly some headers were getting added in request. If I remove all the headers then it works fine. My guess is one of the following two headers was causing problems- "Accept-Encoding" : "gzip, deflate, br",
        "Accept-Language" : "en-US,en;q=0.9",